# How can I change the time zone in Frontaccounting?

Tags: timezone

I have checked with `date_functions.inc` and config.php for time zone. And also I check with setup page as well.  But no  informations about changing the time zone in Frontaccounting.  Is there any simple function to change the time zone or any built in settings available to set the timezone.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to goto the root of frontaccounting than open `includes-> date_functions.inc`. Here add the following code.

```
      date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Katmandu");  // you can add ur timezone here.
```

Here is an article for you to understand it.

[Kvcodes](http://www.kvcodes.com/2014/09/frontaccounting-change-timezones-based-locality/).

You can check Frontaccounting  forum for more help.

Comment: Let me try this one.  Thank you for your prompt response.